# when i restart training from a checkpoint using estiamtor.train() does it continue training using the last batch of data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

My dataset is composed of 293 TFrecords, I'm pretraining BERT from scratch on COLAB TPU's. And since colab TPU SHutdown every ~12 hours, I need to restart training from checkpoints saved on my GCS bucket.

So when training is restarted do estimators continue training from the last batch before shutdown, or they continue training from the first batch in the first TFrecord file?

my tfrecords are created using create_pretraining_data.py from [BERT](https://github.com/google-research/bert) using this command (`ls ./shards/ | xargs -n 1 -P 8 -I{} python3 bert/create_pretraining_data.py --input_file=./shards/{} --output_file=pretraining_data/{}.tfrecord`) where each shard contains 256000 sentences.

Also the here is the link for the COLAB notebook used : [COLAB](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nVn6AFpQSzXBt8_ywfx6XR8ZfQXlKGAz)

Comment: How do you split data to batches?

Comment: @RifatAlptekinÇetin the input_fn used is found here [run_pretraining.py](https://github.com/google-research/bert/blob/master/run_pretraining.py) I think the authors used `d = d.apply(
        tf.contrib.data.map_and_batch(
            lambda record: _decode_record(record, name_to_features),
            batch_size=batch_size,
            num_parallel_batches=num_cpu_threads,
            drop_remainder=True))` for batch splitting